# Postgresql 9.1.9. Updating field with a string concatenated with a field that can be null give error

Tags: postgresql, null, string-concatenation

I don't know if this is a bug from postgres or a misunderstand my.

When I do an update like this:

```
UPDATE table SET empresa = 'NOMBRE ' || city
```

Where city is a field from table and empresa can't be null.

If city is null I get an error from Postgres informing that 'empresa' can't be null, but the whole concatenation is not null, I set a specific string anyway.

Is this a bug from postgres (version 9.1.9 in debian wheezy with backports) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a bug, this is how SQL works. Any expression (concatenation) involving `NULL` returns `NULL`.

You can either use `coalesce()` to make sure that `city` is not null or use the `concat()` function which treats `NULL` similar to an empty string:

```
UPDATE table 
  SET empresa = concat('NOMBRE ', city);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

Here 'NOMBRE ' || city is also NULL if your CITY is NULL. Because any contact with NULL result in NULL.

```
UPDATE table SET empresa = 'NOMBRE ' || COALESCE (city,'')
```